# Authorizing using data return from a Google API

Tags: google-api, firebase

I'm very new to Firebase, so forgive any fundamental lack of knowledge. I'm evaluating it for a project.

Firebase handles Google authentication really well. However, what about authorizing a user based on information returned from a Google API? How can I do this security when Firebase is so heavily client side?

For example, say I'd like to restrict access to firebase data based on whether or not the Google Books API confirms a user owns a book. I know I can pass data to the token like this after auth-ing the user (this is semi-pseudocode):

```
ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
  provider: authData.provider,
  ownsBook: getBookInfo.ownsBook()
});
```

I'd like to use the "ownsBook" parameter to decide whether or not a user can access firebase data, but since this all has to happen client side, what's to stop someone from overriding it manually via the JS console?

How would you normally go about something like this in Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Firebase exposes information from the Google Books API (but I might be wrong).

Aside from that: you'd restrict access to the data using Firebase's security rules: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html .

So if we assume that you have your books and ownerships in a data structure like this:

```
root
  users
    google:3246734
      booksOwned
        book:743267
  books
    book:743267
      title....
```

Your rule might look something like

```
{
  "rules": {
    "book": {
      $book_id: { 
        ".read":
          "root.child(auth.uid).booksOwned.child($book_id).exists()" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So to gain access to a specific book (indicated by `$book_id`) we check whether that book id exists in the users `booksOwned` node.

Comment: Thanks. I'm fairly familiar with how the restrictions would work, but I'm not sure how I'd security get and save the "booksOwned" data to Firebase. This would normally be easy with a server side app because the user does not have access to server side code, but I'm not sure how to proceed with Firebase (a client side app).

Comment: I'd probably do that with a "server-side" process. But don't over-estimate how difficult that is: if you stick to JavaScript, you'd just write a separate script that uses hard-coded credentials or the secret from your Firebase dashboard. You could run that script in node.js or even in a browser tab on your home desktop machine. It's not as resilient as running it on a server, but would accomplish the same thing during dev.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! Server side seems like the way to go in this case.